# Change RIP distance in quagga

Tags: router, rip, quagga

I would like to reproduce the RIP-infinite loop count problem using quagga.

I try to manually set the distance to a route manually but quagga ignores my commands.

```
r1(config-router)# distance 100 192.168.3.0/24
r1(config-router)# do show ip route rip
Codes: K - kernel route, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP,
       O - OSPF, I - IS-IS, B - BGP, A - Babel,
       > - selected route, * - FIB route

R>* 192.168.2.0/24 [10/2] via 192.168.100.2, eth2, 00:00:22
R>* 192.168.3.0/24 [10/3] via 192.168.100.2, eth2, 00:00:22
R>* 192.168.102.0/24 [10/2] via 192.168.100.2, eth2, 00:00:22
```

Any ideas why the distance has no effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things going on here:

1.) The maximum metric/hop count in RIP (v1 and v2) is 15.  Trying to set a metric of 100 isn't going to get you very far in general.

2.) The "distance" command is administrative distance.  This controls the relative priority of routes received in different routing protocols and has literally nothing to do with the infinite count problem within RIP. You'd use this command if, for example, you wanted to manage the behavior such that if 192.168.3.0/24 is received in RIP and OSPF that you'd prefer the RIP version.  In general it's not a great idea to ever play with this value on any router.

If you want to see high metric values reaching infinity try redistributing from static (or another routing protocol) and setting a metric at that point to something close to 15.  So - for example - if you redistribute a static route with a metric of 14 you should see the route make it to one adjacent router but not to one further.

Comment: Saying you shouldn't change the administrative distance values on a router strongly diminishes the value of this answer.  Administrative Distance is policy, and is regularly altered to effect the desired policy of the administrator.

Comment: I said it wasn't a great idea and it isn't.  It is absolutely not regularly altered in common practice in any of the hundreds of large networks I have worked on in the past 20 years.  Is it an available knob?  Sure.  It's an available knob that is almost invariably used either by people backed up to a wall because of bad design decisions or folks who don't understand the many caveats that its use implies.

Comment: There is no inherent "bad design" that goes into changing admin distance.  It has no danger above and beyond any *other* configuration knob you might change - you need to understand what you're doing when you change any config parameter, this one is not special in any way.  The "use" of admin distance has no caveats - it is *always* used - the fact that the defaults for some vendor happen to work for you is convenient, but it isn't something that is only enabled when you set it, and changing the values to reflect local policy is perfectly reasonable.